# Most effectient way to count the number of rows from a result set which contain certain cell values

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am looking for a way to count the number of rows from a result set which contain certain cell values. I want to avoid using multiple queries and arrays.

```
 $fetch_desktops = mysql_query(
     "SELECT 
       ID, 
       description, 
       site, 
       location, 
       user, 
       status, 
       company, 
       MAX(baseline)  
     FROM 
       items 
     WHERE 
       type LIKE 'Desktop' AND isactivebaseline='Yes'  
     GROUP BY ck_config_item ORDER BY ID DESC;"
 );
```

I want to calculate how many results in the array have the status 'Online' and how many have the status 'offline'. With this information I will create a list of which desktops are online and offline.

For example:

Desktops online - **40**

Desktops offline -  **20**

Are there any specific PHP/Mysql functions I can use to do this? I am trying to avoid using **MySQL_num_rows** because I will need to use more than one query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show table structure with some data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a `while()`loop if you cannot use multiple queries:

```
$counter = 0;
$total = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($fetch_desktops)){
     $status = $row -> status;
     if($status == "online"){
        $counter++;
     }
     $total++;
}
// $counter now holds the count of online desktops, $total holds the total of
//desktops in DB, and the offline count can be done as $total - $counter
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for! Thank you very much InterCity :-)

Answer (score 0):

You Try this Sql

```
SELECT  
SUM(IF(type='Desktop',IF(isactivebaseline='Yes',1,0),0)) Desktops online,
SUM(IF(type='Desktop',IF(isactivebaseline !='Yes',1,0),0)) Desktops offline 
FROM items     GROUP BY ck_config_item ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT X.*, Y.count from
(SELECT 
       ID, 
       description, 
       site, 
       location, 
       user, 
       status, 
       company, 
       MAX(baseline)  
     FROM 
       items 
     WHERE 
       type LIKE 'Desktop' AND isactivebaseline='Yes'  
     GROUP BY ck_config_item ORDER BY ID DESC) X,
(SELECT 
       status, COUNT(*) count
     FROM 
       items 
     WHERE 
       type LIKE 'Desktop' AND isactivebaseline='Yes'  
     GROUP BY status) Y     
where X.status=Y.status;
```